# JQuery validation plugin error placement does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I validate a form with the JQuery validator plugin. However, I want to place the error output at a specific place. I tried the Error Placement from the [Validator documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)

```
<div class="form_errors"><!--HERE SHOULD THE ERROR GO --></div>
                            <div class="form_holder_invitee" >
                                <form class="homepage_invitee_form" id="homepage_invitee_form" action="add" method="get">
                                    <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address"
                                        id="email_address_new" type="text placeholder"> <br>
    ...
```

My validation script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#homepage_invitee_form').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            lastName: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent(".form_errors") );
        },
        debug:true

    });

}); // end document.ready
```

I want to place the error into the `<div class="form_errors">`.
However, nothing happens when I submit the form.

Any ideas?

PS.: I also tried that link:

[jQuery validation error position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785361/jquery-validation-error-position)

However, also does not work...

Comment: Are you wanting just one message from one element placed there, or do you want all messages from the form placed there... like an error summary box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your selector and use of `.parent()`. Update your `errorPlacement` to the following and it will work. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tD5z/) to view it working.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    console.log(element);
    element.closest(".form_holder_invitee").prev().append(error);
},
```